# Send email when a user has finished watching something

Tags: ajax, emails

A user watched a video (added listening event to id of video via jwplayer), and a person is notified of said user finishing the video.

```
jwplayer('some-id-of-video').onComplete( function() {
  //$.ajax or .post whatever to send email to a person to let them know without refreshing page
});
```

I want to just add this script to this page (this functionality is only needed for this ONE VIDEO). How do I link the PHP code to send the email? Not a form everything will be a standard response.

This  does not work.

```
$message = array(
  'to' => 'email address',
  'subject' => 'subject text',
  'body' => 'body text',
  'headers' => 'header text'
);

drupal_mail_send($message);
```

Where do I put this? Is this wrong? And if it is wrong, what do I need to fix it? How can I call this code from AJAX?

Answer (score 1):

Create an end point for your ajax request to call using [`hook_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7). In this example I'm passing the UID of the user as an argument.

E.g:

```
/**
* Implementation of hook_menu().
*/
function myModule_menu() {
  $items['mymodule/send-email/%user'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'myModule_ajax_send_email',
    'page arguments' => array(2),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );
  return $items;
}
```

The callback for your menu item will be responsible for actually sending the email. See this question: [How to send email in drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/66209/how-to-send-email-in-drupal)

E.g.:

```
function myModule_ajax_send_email($user) {

  // Here you put the code to actually send the email
  $status = some_logic_to_check_email_sent();

  drupal_json(array('status' => $status));
}
```

So then once your video has finished playing you just need to make an ajax request to your new end point, passing any information required as parameters.
E.g:

```
(function($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.myModule = {
        'attach': function(context) {

            jwplayer('some-id-of-video').onComplete(function(){ 
              //$.ajax or .post whatever to send email to a person to let them know without refreshing page 
              var UID = 1; // actually set UID here
              var url = 'mymodule/send-email/' + UID;
              $.get(url, null, emailCallback);
            });

        }
    }
    var emailCallback = function(response) {
        var result = Drupal.parseJson(response);
        if(result.status !== 1) {
          // Some code to let user know there was an error
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Hi Felix, Thank you for your response. I added a comment yesterday but it is not showing. I tried this. Was this suppose to be a module? If not where do this code go exactly. I'm assuming I can put the js on the page which I have done but where would the php code go? Tried to make a module but did not work. Said I didn't have a .info file which I did.

Comment: Yes, this goes in a custom module. See this page, [Creating Drupal 7.x modules](https://www.drupal.org/developing/modules/7) for some help. 
The JavaScript will go in it's own file as part of the module. See [this answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/12855/11306) for how to add JavaScript to a page.